# PHP mail error: parse error on line 12

Tags: php, email, syntax-error

When I run this it says "PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in your code on line 12 -

if(mail) {$success == true};

### PHP

```
$to = "Admin@mywebsite.com";

$subject = $_POST["Subject"];

$message = 'Hello World!';

$headers = 'From: User@Yourwebsite.com' . "\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: ' . $_POST["Email_From"] . "\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if(mail) {$success == true};
else {$success = false};

if($success){print "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=thanks.html">"};
else{print "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=error.html">"};
```

Comment: `$success == true` should be `$success = true`

Comment: You left out the semicolon. `{$success = true;}`, but you are testing it wrong also, it should be, `if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {$success = true;} else {$success = false;}`, but even that could be simplified to `$success = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);` since `mail` returns a boolean value (true or false).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of syntax issues. Here is the cleaned up code:

```
$to = "Admin@mywebsite.com";

$subject = $_POST['Subject'];

$message = 'Hello World!';

$headers = 'From: User@Yourwebsite.com' . "\r\n" .
  'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['Email_From'] . "\r\n" .
  'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$mail_result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if ($mail_result) {
  $success = true;
}
else {
  $success = false;
}

if($success){
  print '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=thanks.html">';
}
else{
  print '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=error.html">';
}
```

First, your error shows as:

> "PHP Syntax Check: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in your code on line 12

Which is this line:

```
if(mail) {$success == true};
```

Two major issues. First you are checking `mail` which is not a defined constant or even a variable. That should be something like what I set `$mail_result` with the (`$`) in front of the name.  Then your assignment of `$success == true` is not an assignment. That `==` is strictly a comparison operator; it should be `=` for assignment. Then there is no `;` at the end of the assignment, but it appears outside of the braces. Syntax wise, that is not correct. I changed that whole chunk to:

```
$mail_result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if ($mail_result) {
  $success = true;
}
else {
  $success = false;
}
```

Now `$mail_result` is connected to `mail()` as a boolean value. Then the `if()` checks that.  The `$success` is now setting proper assignments with `=` and the line ends with `;` as it should.

Then these two lines are filled with syntax issues as well:

```
if($success){print "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=thanks.html">"};
else{print "<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=error.html">"};
```

You have  the same issue with `;` as the previous issue. But also, your double-quotes (`"`) for the string containment conflict with the double quotes used for the `<meta…` tags. So using single quotes (`'`) for the string containment here & formatting as well.

```
if($success){
  print '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=thanks.html">';
}
else{
  print '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=error.html">';
}
```

But now with the code working, it might make sense to considerate the `$mail_result` setting with the `$success` check like this:

```
$mail_result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if($mail_result){
  print '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=thanks.html">';
}
else{
  print '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=error.html">';
}
```

And it doesn’t make much sense to assign `true` or `false` when that is what `mail()` returns to begin with.

And that said, you might not need the `<meta http-equiv="refresh"…` depending on your final code goal. Superficially you can use the [`header`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function in PHP to better effect like this.

```
$mail_result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

if($mail_result){
  header('Location: thanks.html');
}
else{
  header('Location: error.html');
}
```

Comment: header location would be better than the meta

Comment: mail() already returns a boolean with the success information, so you can shorten your code by writing `$success = mail($to, ...);` and removing the following if/else construct.

Comment: @JakeGould right, I just wanted to point out that the code can be simplified to a (in my mind) more beginner-friendly version :)